# Maxbotixs LV-EZ4 analog read question

Tags: teensy

I am using an external 5 volt power supply to power my Sonar, and I am using a Teensy 3.1 
to read in analog signal  from the sonar. my question is since the teensy is only 3.3v tolerant with analog in, is it safe to use with the maxbotix sonar?

Comment: That is not safe. Maximum voltage on the analog pins is 3.3v, according to the [datasheet](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K20P64M72SF1.pdf). But why don't you power it from 3.3v? Minimal voltage for that unit is 2.5v. And it uses only 2mA.

Comment: Yes, I just did. I assumed that it would be drawing too many mA but I was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converted Gerben's comment to an answer*

---

That is not safe. Maximum voltage on the analog pins is 3.3v, according to the datasheet. But why don't you power it from 3.3v? Minimal voltage for that unit is 2.5v. And it uses only 2mA.